# How to add a collaborator in GitBlit to a repo using the command line?

Tags: git, command, line, gitblit

```
curl -i -u "my_user_name:my_password" -X PUT -d '' 'https://api.github.com/repos/my_gh_userid/my_repo/collaborators/my_collaborator_id'
```

I have found this way using "curl" but this one is for the github. GitBlit is on my on server can I use this way to add a collabrator to a repo ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  You'll have to use the webui.

Comment: So there is no any way to do that via the command line right ?

Comment: There is the powertools plugin which allows you to manipulate user permissions from the command-line over SSH but manipulating the permissions through that technique requires admin permissions.